# Where to start reading The Batman?

Tags: comics, dc, batman, suggested-order

I've recently gotten into comic books and I'm interested in reading the Batman comics. I have no idea where to start. I've seen all of the live action Batman movies so I pretty much know origin stories already.

I'm not interested in Catwoman or Harley Quin, they annoy me.

I love the Riddler and Dr Crane though, and of course the Joker. What are some good recommendations for the comic book beginner in this series?

Comment: No need to just click this [In what order should I read the X-men comics?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46239/in-what-order-should-i-read-the-x-men-comics/46257#46257)

Comment: Outside of starting at the beginning  (ie Year One) I think due to the shear volume of continuity involved this might end up being both a list question, and opinion based.

Comment: He first appeared in [Detective Comics #27](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_27) so really you should just start from there and work your way through.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]
Despite this being sort of a subjective question I have provided a list of what I think of as the **10 Best & Essential Batman** Collections to get started & caught up w/ the *Legend of the Dark Knight*. They feature, either important events in the life and legend of The Batman or important moments which sharpen the character for readers:

- [Batman: Year One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Year_One)
- [Batman: The Long Halloween](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Long_Halloween)
- [Batman: Year Two - Fear the Reaper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Year_Two)
- [Batman: The Cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Cult)
- [Batman: Black And White](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Black_and_White)
- [Batman: Ego and Other Tails](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1309276.Batman)
- [Batman and the Monster Men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_and_the_Monster_Men)
- [Batman: The Killing Joke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Killing_Joke)
- [Batman & Robin: Batman Reborn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_and_Robin_%28comic_book%29#Batman_Reborn_.28Issues_1-3.29)
- [Batman: The Court of the Owls/Night of the Owls](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_The_Court_of_Owls)

[image]
Here are an additional **5 More Collected Batman Stories** that you may find fun and interesting, though be aware some stories listed here out of continuity or take place in a different world/future:

- [Batman: Birth of the Demon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/704586.Batman)
- [Batman: Gotham by Gaslight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotham_by_Gaslight)
- [Batman: Gothic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Gothic)
- [Batman: Hush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Hush)
- [Batman: The Dark Knight Returns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_Returns)

[image]
Finally here are **5 Collected Side-Stories in the Batverse** that you might also enjoy reading:

- [Batman: Turning Points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Turning_Points)
- [Batman & Huntress: A Cry for Blood](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/107081.Batman_Huntress)
- [Batman: A Lonely Place of Dying](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_A_Lonely_Place_of_Dying)
- [Robin: A Hero Reborn](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Robin:_A_Hero_Reborn_%28Collected%29)
- [Nightwing: Love and Bullets](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Nightwing:_Love_and_Bullets)

Comment: Nicely done and definitive list. I am sure the OP will enjoy it.

Comment: Agreed - very streamlined!  Impressed to see Turning Points here, it is not as widely known though an excellent addition to a list like this.  Still I would have dropped **Gothic** for **[Tales of the Demon](http://www.grouchoreviews.com/features/59)**

Comment: Thank you Thaddeus & Hikaru... And you aren't wrong about *Tales of the Demon* being an excellent story Hikaru, but that's the problem with a list like this for a character who has so many great stories.  I was looking to give a broad look so I had to drop things like [Strange Apparitions](http://www.ign.com/articles/2005/06/14/batman-strange-apparitions-review), [Tower of Babel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JLA:_Tower_of_Babel), [RED RAIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_%26_Dracula:_Red_Rain) & even [Broken City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_City_%28comics%29)...to name just a few

Comment: You might want to add some actual elaborations, though, as to why those particular examples are good/interesting/representatic stories and what each has to offer in this regard. Otherwise it's just a link-only answer that I have to take for granted. A mere list without any actual *"why"* doesn't really make the question any less subjective or listy.

Comment: @Fza - I just read Broken City on your recommendation and it was an interesting take on the origin. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome Hikaru! Glad you liked it

Comment: I'd consider adding the [Knightfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Knightfall) arc to this list, which gives a good idea of how motivated Batman is, as well as a large overview of his many villains.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: I thought about KF but 3 things stopped me: 1) It's very-very long 2) It's very unevenly written 3) I don't believe it's in current continuity. Since the person posting was looking to get caught up as well as read some good Bat-Tales I left it out. Honestly if they hadn't been interested in reading current stories I wouldn't have even added The Court of the Owls/Night of the Owls arc as I don't feel it's all that impressive. Really the only part of that arc I really enjoyed was the new Mr Freeze origin (which was excellent).. I think the Fugitive or Gang War arcs were better tales!

Answer (score 3):

### DC Comic's Essential Batman Reading List:

The catalogue *[DC Essential Graphic Novels 2016](http://www.dccomics.com/graphic-novels/dc-comics-essentials-and-chronology-catalogue-2016)* recommends these "essential" Batman graphic novels (in order):

1. *[Batman: Year One](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064W65SO)*
2. *[Batman: The Man Who Laughs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009POHIGG)*
3. *[Batman: The Long Halloween](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064W639K)*
4. *[Batman: Dark Victory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I3OIEGM)*
5. *[Batman: The Killing Joke](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009POHHRG)*
6. *[Batman: A Death in the Family](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0930289447)*
7. *[Batman: Knightfall](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008RNGCAO)*
8. *[Batman: Cataclysm](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1563895277)*
9. *[Batman: No Man's Land](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0097JVVGM)*
10. *[Batman: Hush](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064W652A)*
11. *[Batman: Under the Hood](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009POHIIY)*
12. *[Batman: Batman and Son](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064W67F0)*
13. *[Batman: R.I.P](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064W64I0)*
14. *[Final Crisis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J4ZT9Y0)*
15. *[Batman: Battle for the Cowl](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009POHIES)*
16. *[Batman and Robin: Batman Reborn](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064W64K8)*
17. *[Batman: The Return of Bruce Wayne](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016AWI4D6)*
18. *[Batman: The Black Mirror](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009POHHQM)*
19. *[Batman: Zero Year](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MV1NYKY)*
20. *[Batman: The Court of Owls](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008J2GAKU)*
21. *[Batman: The Night of the Owls](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BCOS47O)*
22. *[Batman: Death of the Family](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EIPA3HS)*
23. *[Batman Eternal](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MV1NYJ0)*
24. *[Batman: Endgame](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013TGYL4M)*

They also present 25 graphic novels as being their overall most "culturally relevant." The ones that feature Batman as a major character and aren't on the above list are:

1. *[The Dark Knight Returns](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064W66HY)*
2. *[Justice League Volume 1: Origin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008J2GFV4)*
3. *[Superman/Batman Vol. 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JRILLTK)*
4. *[Superman: Red Son](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009POHHR6)*
5. *[Batman: Earth One](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00W8FOVUA)*
6. *[Injustice: Gods Among Us  Vol. 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ET886Q4)*

Answer (score -1):

I'd add the Batman: Year Zero and Death of The Family story arcs as well. Also try A Death in the Family, and Under the (Red) Hood.

Comment: If you're just adding onto another answer, you'd be better off just commenting. Otherwise, go ahead an write up a list with all of your suggestions to flesh this out into a full answer.